# Proving $A$ is not invertible if $AB=A^2B^2-(AB)^2$ and $\det(B)=2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $2\times 2$ matrices with real element such that

$$AB=A^2B^2-(AB)^2
\qquad\text{and}\qquad 
\det(B)=2.$$
Show that $A=0$.

My Attempt:

\begin{align}
AB=A^2B^2-(AB)^2
&\implies A=A^2B-ABA &&\text{(since $|B|\neq0$)} \\
&\implies A = A(AB) - A(BA) \\
&\implies \operatorname{tr}(A) = 0
\end{align}

Also, by Cayley Hamilton theorem I could get $$A^2=-|A|I$$

This is all I could gather.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $$ A=A(AB-BA),$$ since $AB-BA=I$ is impossible, you get that $A$ is not invertible. So $|A|=0$, and from your last equality $$A^2=-|A|I=0.$$

You cannot improve that. Let 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix} 0&2\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then your conditions are satisfied:
$$
AB=A^2B^2-(AB)^2,\ \ \ \det B=2.
$$

Comment: So you mean to say that question should have been 'Prove that $A^2=O$'.

Comment: Well, I'm not a mind reader!  As stated, the question asks to prove something that is not true. Whether the mistake is in the hypotheses or in the conclusion is not for me to tell.

Comment: How do we know $AB-BA \neq I$?

Comment: @Phys251: consider the trace.

Comment: @MartinArgerami So it means that characterstic equation  of the square matrix $A$ has two equal roots both being equal to zero and therefore $A=O$ can be said to be minimal equation of the square matrix $A$. So $A$ could be a null matrix after all though you have a very nice counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

$$\det AB=2\det A = \det A \det ( I - BA) \det B = 2 \det A \det (I-BA) $$
$$\det A = \det A \det (I - BA)$$

The result follow from this.

Comment: How do you get from the determinant identity to $A=0$?